# How to combine constraint CHECK in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, check-constraints

There is a following table:

```
CREATE TABLE LectureHalls
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
floor INTEGER CHECK (floor <= 4),
classroom INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT sc_unique_lectureHall UNIQUE (id, floor, classroom),
CONSTRAINT sc_unique_lectureHall2 UNIQUE (floor, classroom);
);
```

Is it possible to create such a constraint in sql so that when floor = 1 classroom> 0 and classroom <= 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
create table lecturehalls (
    id serial primary key,
    floor integer check (floor <= 4),
    classroom integer not null,
    unique (floor, classroom),
    check(floor is distinct from 1 or (classroom > 0 and classroom <= 30))
);
```

Note that I removed the unique constraint on `(id, floor, classroom)`: `id` is the primary key of the table, so this is a no-op anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
CREATE TABLE LectureHalls
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
floor INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (floor BETWEEN 1 AND 4),
classroom INTEGER NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY (floor, classroom),
CHECK (floor = 1 AND classroom BETWEEN 1 AND 30) 
);
```

This form allows expansion to more floors:

```
CREATE TABLE LectureHalls
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
floor INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (floor BETWEEN 1 AND 4),
classroom INTEGER NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY (floor, classroom),
CHECK (floor = 1 AND classroom BETWEEN 1 AND 30 OR
       floor = 2 AND classroom BETWEEN 1 AND 15 OR
       floor = 3 AND classroom BETWEEN 1 and 24) 
);
```